# How to mock a private inner class

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mocking, mockito

I have a spring application and I want to create a unitary test on a controller like this one. The problem is that the Wrapper class is a private inner class, so Wrapper is not understood in the test. Is it possible to mock it with Mockito without changing the controller class. I can use prepareData() to get an instance of the object, but I don't know if this could be used to mock that object.

Thanks

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    private class Wrapper {
        private Object1 field1;
        private Object2 field2;
        private Object1 method1(){
           ...
        }
        private Object2 method1(){
           ...
        }
    }

    @ModelAttribute("data")
    public Wrapper prepareData() {
            return new Wrapper ();
}

    public String save(@ModelAttribute("data") Wrapper wrapper, BindingResult result, Model model){
        ...
    }
}
```

So in my test I would have something like this

```
@Test
public void usernameEmpty(){

    BindingResult result = Mockito.mock(BindingResult.class);
    Model model = Mockito.mock(Model.class);
    Wrapper data = //how to mock it
    when(data.method1()).then(new Foo1());
    when(data.method2()).then(new Foo2());
    String returned = controller.save(data, result, model);
    ....
}
```

Comment: My I ask why you want to do this? You will likely end up testing the wrong code. If the inner class has dependencies (probably obtained through the controller?) mock those. Wait? Does your code compile? If Wrapper is private class can you use it as an argument to a public method?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes  I'm new in testing. I just wanted to make a test on the save method so I needed to mock the Wrapper object so I could define the return objects when some methods are invoked on it. Yes the controller compiles (The test doesn't but this is the problem - that I can't use Wrapper class in the test). Maybe there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Java just surprised me again (on the negative). This makes me powerless to help without a Java compiler on hand :( Anyway, even if allowed, I don't think it is a good design to have a public method that requires knowledge of privates. It breaks encapsulation. How are you going to use that method in actual real code? Is it possible?

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes you're right I think I'll change it to public

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your test is on methods, but it tests the whole class behavior. If your inner class is private then its an implementation detail. Something that the test shouldn't know. It there's a lot of behaviour in that inner-class and you want to test it independently maybe you should make it public and separate from this class.

Maybe you think: but then... it's a lot of code to test (a very big indivisible thing), can't I test something smaller? Well... yes. Test Driven Development mandates to make a minimal implementation and add more code only if you add more tests. So you start with some test and minimal implementation and evolve both of them until the tests have all the specification and the code all the implementation.

So don't worry about private inner classes. Test your class contract!

Comment: And good luck with unit testing! It gives a lot of confidence and the ability to change without (inadvertidally)  breaking the thing!

Comment: It is not very good - it will be integration test. You broke one of the main principles of test driven development - test should be simple!

Comment: Yes. But TDD is a development methodology: first write test, then write code. In that case the OP maybe get another design (more simple and more modular), and not get a private inner class. In this situation it's only testing an already existent code. Said that: I agree it's not a simple test but a private inner class is not extractable from the container class so altough it's not simple, it's not an integration test IMHO (anyway, the important part is "test" :)

Comment: I don't think so. Example: if file elaborates some information it sometimes requires internal cache, usually it can be made like private inner class.