# How do you mock a method which uses a private static inner class as a parameter?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a class with a method that takes a single parameter. This parameter is a nested class inside the mocked class, but it is private (And static but I don't think that makes much of a difference to this). How do I go about mocking this method?

Example:

```
public class myClass {

    public anotherObject;

    public myClass(AnotherObject anotherObject) {
        this.anotherObject = anotherObject;
    }

    public void exec() {
        //Some instructions ...

        //This second method is inside another completely seperate class.
        anotherObject.secondMethod(new NestedClass());
    }

    private static class NestedClass {
        public NestedClass() {
             //Constructor
        }
        //Variables and methods, you get the picture
    }
}
```

In the above example secondMethod(...) is the method that I want to mock.

All attempts to find other examples of this problem just return results relating to mocking a single private nested class, or mocking static classes, which aren't completely relevant to this and don't seem to provide any work around that I can figure out.

---

EDIT:
I'm looking for some sort of solution that looks like this:

```
@Test
public void testExec() {
    AnotherObject anotherObject = mock(AnotherObject.class);
    when(anotherObject.secondMethod(any(NestedClass.class))).thenReturn(0);

    MyClass testThisClass = new MyClass(anotherObject);
}
```

---

Notes: I'm not allowed to make modifications to the code I'm afraid, I am only allowed to create these tests to make sure the current implementation works later down the line when modification are made to it.

Comment: a public class that takes a private static class as a parameter? That does not make a lot of sense: nobody can call that method from outside `myClass`. I would either make `secondMethod` private or `NestedClass` public...

Comment: mock a private inner class : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593201/how-to-mock-a-private-inner-class

Comment: Hi, I tried to simplify my actual problem down to this, but in doing so I may have made it seem like a non-issue. In reality it calls a method in a completely seperate second class, using the private static nestedClass. I will update my inital question now that you've pointed out this simplified example has a major flaw.

Comment: @ParaSara - It's hard to explain without going into a lot of detail, but the whole reason I'm mocking this method out is because for the specific test I'm trying to conduct I don't care at all about what this mocked method does, and if it fails (Which is might due to a possible lack of connection to outside sources while testing) I still want the test to pass if the rest of this method succeeds. Also, that example is just if I want to mock the private inner class itself, I don't, I just want to use it inside some sort of any(NestedClass.class) notation.

Comment: @Seb What is the signature of that  other method in the second class (here represented by `secondMethod()`? It can't refer to this private static class as it can't see it.

Comment: @Biziclop - Sorry, could you explain which things you're referring to with 'other method' and 'second class'?

Comment: `In reality it calls a method in a completely seperate second class, using the private static nestedClass.` This is what I was referring to. That method, if it is indeed in a separate class, can't possibly use this private class as its parameter.

Comment: If your inner class is private then its an implementation detail. Something that the test shouldn't know. It there's a lot of behaviour in that inner-class and you want to test it independently maybe you should make it public and separate from this class.

Comment: @Biziclop - Sorry, I'm not sure what to tell you other than that it does work. The exec method in myClass gets called, and then it creates a new instance of NestedClass and passes this as a parameter to another method in a completely seperate class. My application runs fine, it does what I expect it to do and I can debug it to see it working like this. I'm setting up these unit tests now incase I break it in the future.

Comment: @ParaSara - Unfortunately I can not make modifications to the code that I am testing, this is beyond my control and a restriction that I simply have to work within. Secondly I don't care about the behaviour of the nestedclass. For my test it is created and passed off to this secondMethod, where I no longer care what happens to it because that is out of the scope of this particular test. This is why I want to mock the method.

Comment: I've attempted to further clear up what I'm trying to accomplish in my question.

Comment: @Seb I don't doubt that it works, what I'm saying is that your simplification isn't representative of what you've got. We'd know better if we saw the definition of `anotherObject` (or rather, its class).

Comment: when(anotherObject.secondMethod(any(NestedClass.class))).thenReturn(0); you can call inside myClass only. not allowed any separate class.

Comment: @biziclop - Does it help to know that NestedClass is a Runnable, and anotherObject is a custom pool manager that assigns a thread to execute it? I left this out thinking it might just overly complicate matters. In the end I have a mocked instance of anotherObject that I pass into myClass when I start the test, I just need to know how to tell the anotherObject mock to do nothing when it gets to the method. The main problem I have is I can't just write any(NestedClass.class) inside the when declaration.

Comment: @ParaSara - Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Seb Of course it helps, because it means you can just pass any `Runnable` to that other method. And then you also mock out that method to throw away its parameter and return a constant value.

Comment: @Biziclop - Ah, I did not think of that. Thank you very much. Sorry for confusing matters by trying to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the requirement correctly, add one method say executeSecondMethod(). Call this method in your main method class.

```
public class myClass {
    public void exec() {
    //Some instructions ...

     secondMethod(new NestedClass());
    }

    public void secondMethod(NestedClass example) {
        //Some instructions that I want to just mock out...
    }

    private static class NestedClass {
        //Variables and methods, you get the picture
    }

    public static executeSecondMethod(){
        secondMethod(new NestedClass()); // pass the nested class object here
    }


}

public class mainClass{

    public static void main(){
        executeSecondMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the program I'm working on everything works. It already manages to call the secondMethod with the NestedClass parameter. My problem is that I'm trying to mock this method.